# Identify the bright object to the left of the moon

Tags: the-moon, jupiter, night-sky

I'm seeing the sky at 23:00 on September 29, 2023, from the east of Algeria's point of view. To the left of the moon, there is something very bright. I need to confirm if it's Jupiter?

(My camera doesn't capture the brightness very well)

[image: The bright object]

Comment: It's Jupiter.  You might want to search for some planetarium software and browse around.  There are a alot available and a lot of fun.

Comment: @GregMiller Thank you for your answer, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it is Jupiter. The night seems cloudy, so we can rule out all the stars. Furthermore the apparent magnitude of that planet seems similar to Jupiter, -2.65. Venus has comparable magnitude, but it already had set at 10:47 pm. Saturn had southern angular seperation to the Moon whereas Jupiter perfectly fits the picture

As Greg Miller suggested, I used a planetarium software, to recreate the night sky from the east of Algeria specifically Ezzaquia, part of eastern Algeria.

Image:

[image]
Note: It seems like Jupiter rised at 00:59 not 23:00, but Saturn which rised on time did not seem to fit the given description, so I came to conclusion

Thank you, Hope it helps you!